# C++ stream as a member variable

Tags: c++, variables, stream, member

I've got a C++ class which I would like to hold a stream used for logging.

The stream should be able to be set (and possibly reset) after the construction of the object.

It should be possible to set the stream as `std::cout`, or as a file stream to log to a file, or as a stringstream which does nothing more than ignore the data (a `/dev/null` of sorts).  In any case, it should be an `ostream` type object, which the creator of the object can reset at any time.  The class itself is oblivious to the concrete stream type.

I could accomplish this with a pointer to an ostream, but then the syntax becomes a little annoying, having to use the deref operator:

```
(*m_log) << "message";
```

rather than

```
m_log << "message";
```

But I can't use references, as the stream object needs to be possibly reset after the object has been initialized.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this, i.e., avoid using pointers, but still be able to reset after construction?

Comment: Why don't you provide a small member function returning a reference to your stream ? something along the way of: ostream& mlog() {return *m_log;}. You would then write: mlog() << "message";

Comment: Use a pointer, and begin your function with `std::ostream & o = *m_log;`.

Comment: @fjardon: Why don't you provide that as a small answer? ;P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reset streams: see it live on **https://ideone.com/Ci4eo**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Logger
{
    Logger(std::ostream& os) : m_log(os.rdbuf()) { }

    std::streambuf* reset(std::ostream& os) 
    {
        return m_log.rdbuf(os.rdbuf());
    }

    template <typename T> friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& os, const T& t)
    { os.m_log << t; return os; }

    friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& os, std::ostream& ( *pf )(std::ostream&))
    { os.m_log << pf; return os; }

  private:
    std::ostream m_log;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Logger logto(std::cout);

    logto << "Hello world" << std::endl;

    logto.reset(std::cerr);
    logto << "Error world" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, exactly along the lines of what I was looking for. It could be expanded to (optionally) add a 2nd stream, for example, creating a T. I would uprate this... if I had enough reputation. (:  Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for facilities such as Tee-streams, have a look at [Boost Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=1), e.g. the [Tee Filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html#tee_filter) in combination with [Pipelines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/pipelines.html)

Answer (score 5):

Why trouble yourself?

```
class foo{
public:
  // ..
private:
  std::ostream& log() const{ return *m_log; }
  mutable std::ostream* m_log;
};
```

And just use `log() << "blah\n";` instead.

Comment: @James: I have no idea what you mean. ♪

Comment: There was no * in the log method before I just refreshed the page.

Comment: By suggesting to remove the parenthesis in this tip by using a macro I will become the most hated person of the day.

Comment: @user331471 - Seconded. I recommend the "don't use a macro unless there really is no other way" rule, which that would clearly violate.

Comment: Ok, then the educational purpose of my last comment should be to make clear that further "code enhancements" through using macros should not be taken into consideration...