# c++ rvalue of moveable type in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using C++11 and trying to construct a class that owns a movable type like this:

```
class foo {
    std::istream input;

public:
    foo(std::istream && in): input(in) { }
};
```

And then instantiate the object:

```
foo var1(std::ifstream("/tmp/something"));
```

But the compiler always complains that I am calling a deleted constructor. Is this even possible?

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp 
foo.cpp:7:30: error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>')
    foo(std::istream && in): input(in) { }
                             ^     ~~
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/istream:1740:23: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
extern template class basic_istream<char>;
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Could you post the compiler error?

Comment: There are no copy constructors for streams the call input(in) is making a copy (since in is named it is no longer an rvalue reference).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not copy (or even move) the abstract stream type `std::istream`.  You can hold them by reference, but that doesn't seem to be what your code wants to do.

As you are passing in a `std::ifstream`, I'll assume that this is the type of stream you really want to deal with.  Unlike `std::istream`, `std::ifstream` is a concrete type.  And this type is movable, though not copyable.

The answer hmjd had, and that you marked correct, is the best way to code this:

```
#include <fstream>

class foo
{
    std::ifstream input;
public:
    foo(std::ifstream&& in): input(std::move(in)) { }
};
```

Explanation:  The `foo` constructor will only accept rvalue `std::ifstream`s, which is correct.  But once you're inside this constructor, the variable `in` is no longer an rvalue (it is an lvalue).  And thus you need to cast it back to an rvalue (using `std::move`) to move construct the data member `input`.

This is the same pattern that you would use with any move-only type (`stringstream`, `unique_ptr`, `future`, `unique_lock`, etc.).

Comment: This does not compile with gcc 4.6.1:
In constructor 'foo::foo(std::ifstream&&)':
error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)' Perhaps this is due to incomplete support on GCC's behalf?

Comment: @mark: Correct, this would be a gcc bug.  `basic_ifstream(basic_ifstream&& rhs);` is specified in 27.9.1.7 [ifstream.cons] / p4:  *Effects:* Move constructs from the rvalue `rhs`. ...

Comment: your solution is eactly what I tried first of all... Hopefully GCC will fix this in the near future.

Comment: Hmm you can probably get around spotty compiler/library support by using my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8446901/85371

Answer (score 3):

How about a solution that uses unique_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class foo {
    unique_ptr<ifstream> input;

public:
    foo( unique_ptr<std::ifstream>&& in ): input( std::move(in) ) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ifstream> myStream( new ifstream( "something" ) );
    foo f( std::move( myStream ) );
    return 0;
}
```

This could be improved by using a hand rolled make_unique template (see: [suttersmill gotw #102](http://herbsutter.com/2011/12/02/gotw-102-exception-safe-function-calls-difficulty-710/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the important line in the question is this:

```
foo var1(std::ifstream("/tmp/something"));
```

The questioner just wants this, or something like it, to 'just work', and the questioner doesn't actually require moves or anything like that. (Is this correct?)

Here's an answer:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class foo {
public:
        typedef typename std :: remove_reference<T> :: type value_type;
        value_type input;
        template <class ... Args>
        foo(Args... args): input(args...) {}
};

int main() {
        foo<std::ifstream> var1("/tmp/something");
}
```

Do you require a version that only accepts types which can be converted to istream ? You could include another members of type `istream&` and initialize this with `input`. This would force the template to only use suitable types.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to forget about `move` and `&&`. You can't easily construct an `istream` - it's a very basic type which doesn't have many suitable [constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/istream/). <strike>The error is telling you that `istream` can't be moved.</strike>

You might have to explicitly control the lifetime yourself, and have foo keep a reference.

```
class foo {
public:
    std::istream &input;

    foo(std::istream& in): input(in) { }
};

std::ifstream a_suitable_variable ("/tmp/something");
foo(a_suitable_variable);
```

Another option is to just pass in the filename to the constructor.

```
class foo {
public:
    std::ifstream input; // NOT a reference this time

    foo(string s): input(s) { }
};
foo("/tmp/something");
```

Comment: +1 for the simple alternate option of just passing the file name :)